# Как динамически подгрузить контент в метку в балуне-аккордионе кластера?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подгрузка в обычную метку - ок.

Но события ***objectManager.clusters.events.add('balloonopen', function (event) {})*** не работает.

Если использовать ***map_index.balloon.events.add('click'...),*** то не могу получить ID метки, чтобы выполнить дальнейшие манипуляции для загрузки контента.

Мне сойдёт любой вариант, как при раскрытии балуна кластера грузить все входящие в состав кластера метки, так и при клике на саму метку.

Comment: Этот пример не подойдёт https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/om_balloon_ajax ?

Comment: @se0ga, да, спасибо, видимо я невнимательно искал примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В песочнице JS API Яндекс карт есть пример, который полностью отражает, то что вы хотите сделать: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/om_balloon_ajax

Вот код:

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
    // Получим объект, на котором открылся балун.
    var id = e.get('objectId'),
        geoObject = objectManager.objects.getById(id);
    // Загрузим данные для объекта при необходимости.
    downloadContent([geoObject], id);
});

objectManager.clusters.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
    // Получим id кластера, на котором открылся балун.
    var id = e.get('objectId'),
    // Получим геообъекты внутри кластера.
        cluster = objectManager.clusters.getById(id),
        geoObjects = cluster.properties.geoObjects;

    // Загрузим данные для объектов при необходимости.
    downloadContent(geoObjects, id, true);
});

function downloadContent(geoObjects, id, isCluster) {
    // Создадим массив меток, для которых данные ещё не загружены.
    var array = geoObjects.filter(function (geoObject) {
                return geoObject.properties.balloonContent === 'идет загрузка...' ||
                    geoObject.properties.balloonContent === 'Not found';
            }),
    // Формируем массив идентификаторов, который будет передан серверу.
        ids = array.map(function (geoObject) {
                return geoObject.id;
            });
    if (ids.length) {
        // Запрос к серверу.
        // Сервер обработает массив идентификаторов и на его основе
        // вернет JSON-объект, содержащий текст балуна для
        // заданных меток.
        ymaps.vow.resolve($.ajax({
                // Обратите внимание, что серверную часть необходимо реализовать самостоятельно.
                //contentType: 'application/json',
                //type: 'POST',
                //data: JSON.stringify(ids),
                url: 'content.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false
            })).then(function (data) {
                    // Имитируем задержку от сервера.
                    return ymaps.vow.delay(data, 1000);
            }).then(
                function (data) {
                    geoObjects.forEach(function (geoObject) {
                        // Содержимое балуна берем из данных, полученных от сервера.
                        // Сервер возвращает массив объектов вида:
                        // [ {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна"}, ...]
                        geoObject.properties.balloonContent = data[geoObject.id].balloonContent;
                    });
                    // Оповещаем балун, что нужно применить новые данные.
                    setNewData();
                }, function () {
                    geoObjects.forEach(function (geoObject) {
                        geoObject.properties.balloonContent = 'Not found';
                    });
                    // Оповещаем балун, что нужно применить новые данные.
                    setNewData();
                }
            );
    }

    function setNewData(){
        if (isCluster && objectManager.clusters.balloon.isOpen(id)) {
            objectManager.clusters.balloon.setData(objectManager.clusters.balloon.getData());
        } else if (objectManager.objects.balloon.isOpen(id)) {
            objectManager.objects.balloon.setData(objectManager.objects.balloon.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/355215)

Comment: Если ссылка на официальную песочницу js api яндекс карт станет недействительной, то это значит, что весь проект js api яндекс карт скорее всего умер и вопрос перестанет иметь смысл.

Comment: @se0ga, яндекс может сменить домен для примеров или выпустить новую мажорную версию и под неё сделать новый сайт с документацией, а потом прибить старый. Т.е. могут быть случаи, что вопрос актуален, API существует, а ссылка невалидна)

Comment: Яндекс до сих пор поддерживает ссылки на примеры версий которые выпущены более 10 лет назад. Но добавил код)